# How to locate compiler for mex in matlab 2016a?

Tags: matlab, mex

Using Matlab 2013b, I ran the command `mex -setup` and I get the result:

```
>> mex -setup

Welcome to mex -setup.  This utility will help you set up  
a default compiler.  For a list of supported compilers, see  
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013b/win64.html 

Please choose your compiler for building MEX-files: 

Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n? n
```

My problem is, that under Matlab2016a I can't see this message - I only get the following result:

```
>> mex -setup
MEX configured to use 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 (C)' for C language compilation.
Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to support MATLAB
     variables with more than 2^32-1 elements. In the near future
     you will be required to update your code to utilize the
     new API. You can find more information about this at:
     http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.

To choose a different language, select one from the following:
 mex -setup C++ 
 mex -setup FORTRAN
```

Please, how I could see the message

`"Welcome to mex -setup.  This utility will help you set up etc"`

Thank you very much.

Comment: Because it is already configured. The second message is telling you "hey, nothing else to do here, its already configured for `'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 (C)'`"

Comment: Thank you for yor help. I want to change the compiler, namely I want to use intel c++compiler. How  could I do that ?

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/changing-default-compiler.html), if there is [a supported compiler](https://uk.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/support/sysreq/files/SystemRequirements-Release2013b_SupportedCompilers.pdf), it will appear when you type `mex   -setup C++`

Answer (score 1):

From the [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/changing-default-compiler.html):

> To change the default C++ compiler, type:
>
> ```
> mex -setup cpp
> ```

This way you can change to different compilers *if you have them*. Calling `mex -setup` sets the C compiler, which may be different.